# why does my foreign key code show a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm attempting to create a table in a relational database that has a foreign key and a SQL syntax error consistently occurs.

I am using PHP and mySQL (i've removed any non interacting tables that only hold data and don't contribute to the relations)

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS logins( 
        loginID int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        buildingID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES buildings(buildingID))
```

buildings is another table, which has the primary key "buildingID"

the error that shows is

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES buildings(buildingID), login varchar(255)...'

this error doesn't happen when the foreign key is removed, the table creates with no errors; and I create this table after i create the table that the foreign key references.

i have tried using the other syntax:

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS logins( 
        loginID int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        buildingID int,
        PRIMARY KEY(loginID),
        FOREIGN KEY (buildingID) REFERENCES buildings(buildingID))
```

to no avail: the same error happens

what is my mistake here, and how can I change my code to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide buildings table schema. Let's see how it is formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is that primary keys are not permitted to be unsigned, i changed this one thing in my code and the error went away

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Few typos.

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS logins( 
        loginID int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        buildingID int,
        PRIMARY KEY(loginID),
        FOREIGN KEY (buildingID) REFERENCES buildings(buildingID))
```

this works fine

Comment: i seem to get an error with this code that says "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" and ive directly ctrl c+v'd it into my code, any idea why? im completely lost. - i dont know if this is relevant but im using xampp if that helps

Comment: the typos you have pointed out do appear to just be me writing my code wrong into the question form, apologies.